# Way to use overlaying custom video controls without conflicting with native textTrack support

Tags: html5-video

In case you are using custom video controls overlaying over the video in conjunction with the track element. The subtitles/captions are often displayed below those controls (especially in Safari6 or Opera.next).

Is there a good way (i.e. CSS or not so good JS) to place the subtitles above the controls.

I know that you can change the line position directly inside of your WebVTT file, but this isn't really suitable, because the placement of the subtitles inside of the WebVTT file are "semantic", while the position definition I need, depends on the layout of the player. (It doesn't really make sense to change the WebVTT file, as soon as you change the skin of a player).

Currently all custom media controls scripts with track element support, simply do remove the native implementation and handle displaying the cues thier own, which isn't really what polyfilling means to me.